# How to check whether a bucket exists in GCS with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = ['symbol_wise_nse', 'symbol_wise_final']

for i in bucket:
    if client.get_bucket(i).exists():
        BUCKET = client.get_bucket(i)
```

if the bucket exists i want to do client.get_bucket. How to check whether the bucket exists or not?

Comment: It seems you have code that is checking for this already. I’m assuming it’s not working as expected. Are you getting an error message? Is the condition never being triggered? Or is this intended as pseudo code which does not compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to check if the bucket exists or not, however you will get an error if you try to access a non existent bucket.

I would recommend you to either list the buckets in the project with [`storage_client.list_buckets()`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets) and then use the response to confirm if the bucket exists in your code, or if you wish to perform the `client.get_bucket` in every bucket in your project, you can just iterate through the response directly.

Hope you find this information useful

Comment: There is a method, its called `exists()`, see https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html.

Answer (score 11):

Another option that doesn't use try: except is:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()    

bucket = ['symbol_wise_nse', 'symbol_wise_final']
for i in bucket:
    BUCKET = client.bucket(i)
    if BUCKET.exists():
        BUCKET = client.get_bucket(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

buckets = ['symbol_wise_nse', 'symbol_wise_final']

for i in buckets:
  try:
       bucket = client.get_bucket(i)
       print(bucket)
  except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (re-using params in question):

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import Bucket

client = storage.Client()
exists = Bucket(client, 'symbol_wise_nse').exists()
```